# :hover cant get third menu level to display in IE6

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-6

I'm trying to get a suckerfish style dropdown menu to work in IE6 using whatever:hover but cant for the life of me get the 3rd level to display! Its driving me nuts any help on this would be greatly appreciated.

[My fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hQuYp/1/)

Heres the code
HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <body>
        <header>
            <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styleIE.css" />
        </header>
        <form>
            <div id="container">
               <div id = "menu">
                    <ul id="nav">
                        <li><a class="rhlinkstart" href="#"><span>Home</span></a></li>
                        <li><a class="rhlink" href="#"><span>Blad<br> Securities</span></a></li>
                        <li><a class="rhlink" href="#"><span>Market<br> Update</span></a></li>
                        <li><a class="rhlink" href="#"><span>Membership</span></a></li>
                        <li><a class="rhlink" href="#"><span>asdasd Info</span></a>
                            <ul>
                                <li><a class="linkchild" href="#"><img class = "arrow" src="Images/arrow.gif" alt="&#9658;">About the DOOB</a>
                                    <ul>
                                        <li><a class="linkchild" href="#">DOOB Explained</a></li>
                                        <li><a class="linkchild" href="#">DOOB Jurisdications</a></li>
                                    </ul>
                                </li>
                                <li><a class="linkchild" href="#">International Recogintion</a></li>
                                <li><a class="linkchild" href="#"><img class = "arrow" src="Images/arrow.gif" alt="&#9658;">Advantages of listing</a> 
                                     <ul>
                                        <li><a class="linkchild" href="#">Advantages of Listing</a></li>
                                        <li><a class="linkchild" href="#">Offers</a></li>
                                    </ul>
                                </li>
                                <li><a class="linkchild" href="#">Advantages Of Membership</a></li>
                                <li><a class="linkchild" href="#">Publications</a></li>
                                <li><a class="linkchild" href ="#">Links</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li><a class="rhlinkend" href="#"><span>Contact Us</span></a></li>
                       <li>&nbsp;</li>
                    </ul>
               </div>
            </div>
        </form>
     </body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
body{
  line-height:1;
  background: #e3e3e3; 
  behavior: url("csshover3.htc");
}

/*------------------------------------*\
 Main
\*------------------------------------*/
div#container
{
    width:1024px; 
    margin:0 auto;
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: white;
    border: 1px solid #8b8b8b;
 }

.contentwrapper {
    width: 964px;
    margin: 0px auto;
    text-align: left;
    height: 100%;
}

.clearall {
 clear: both;
}


/*------------------------------------*\
   Home Page - Menu Styling
\*------------------------------------*/

#menu {
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding-left: 2%;
    height: 47px;
    position: relative;
    top: 0;
    border: 1px solid rgb(140,51,61);
    font-size: 75%;
    display: block;
}
#nav {
     margin:0;
     padding:0;
     list-style-type:none;
     list-style-position:outside;
     position:relative;
     height:47px;
     background: none;
     background-color: transparent;
     width: 100%;
}

#nav ul {
     margin:0;
     padding:0;
     list-style-type:none;
     list-style-position:outside;
     position:relative;
}

#nav a.rhlinkstart:link, #nav a.rhlinkstart:active, #nav a.rhlinkstart:visited {
    position: relative;
    float:left;
    font-family: Georgia;
    color: rgb(131,0,26);
    width: 148px;
    text-align: center;
    height: 47px;
    margin-right: -.07em;
    margin-left: 0.5em;
    line-height: 47px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

#nav a.rhlink:link, #nav a.rhlink:active, #nav a.rhlink:visited {
    position: relative;
    float:left;
    font-family: Georgia;
    color: rgb(131,0,26);
    width: 148px;
    text-align: center;
    height: 47px;
    margin-left: -47px;
    line-height: 47px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
}

#nav a.rhlinkend:link, #nav a.rhlinkend:active, #nav a.rhlinkend:visited {
    float:left;
    position: relative;
    color: rgb(131,0,26);
    width: 148px;
    height: 47px;
    line-height: 47px;
    margin-left: -3.780em;
    font-family: Georgia;
    text-decoration: none;
}

#nav li {
    float:left;
    position:relative;
    display: block;
}

li a.rhlink span {
    line-height: 1em;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-align: center;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

#nav li a.rhlink:hover, 
#nav li a.rhlinkstart:hover,
#nav li a.rhlinkend:hover
{
    background: red;
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
}

#nav a.linkchild:link,
#nav a.linkchild:active,
#nav a.linkchild:visited 
{
    display:block;
    padding:0px 10px;
    text-decoration:none;
    color: white;
    background: pink ;
}

#nav a.linkchild:hover {
   background: rgb(118,0,18);
   color: white;
}

#nav ul {
    position:absolute;
    top:47px;
    left:0;
    margin: 0;
    width:200px;
    display:none;
}

#nav li ul a {
    width:15em;
    float:left;
    display: inline-block;
    line-height: 2.5em;
    text-align: left;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

#nav li {
     display: inline-block !important;
     float: left;   
}

#nav li a {
    display: inline-block !important;   
    vertical-align: middle;
}

#nav ul ul {
    top:auto;
}

#nav li ul ul {
    left:200px;
    margin:0;
}

#nav ul ul li ul {
    left:200px;
    margin:0;
}

#nav ul ul {
   display:none;
}

#nav li:hover ul {
   display:block;
}

/* 2 and 13 */
#nav ul ul, 
#nav li:hover ul ul { 
   display:none;
}

/* 12 and 23*/
#nav li:hover ul, #nav li:hover li:hover ul { 
   display:block;
}
```

Comment: Thats useful....not... its what the client needs

Comment: @davey - it is what your client needs. It may not be what he wants to hear, but it is what he needs.

Comment: your `<header>` tag should actually be a `<head>` tag, and above the `<body>`, not inside it. Yes, `<header>` is a valid HTML5 tag, but in the context you've used it, you should be using `<head>`.

Comment: Have you tried an original suckerfish menu in IE6

Comment: In your fiddle I don't even see the second level in IE6 (Virtaul PC, XP)

Comment: I've resolved the issue I recreated the entire menu from scratch and got it working, thanks for all the comments guys. Still dont why it wasnt working on the original.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the comments guys, in the end I rewrote the menu from scratch and got it working in IE6. I know IE6 is dead but my clients biggest client uses this browser :( so it had to be done.

Comment: I know there's nothing you can do about it, but your client's biggest client is likely to have major problems if they stick with IE6 much longer. When support for it is finally dropped completely in about a year or so, I predict there will be a spate of attacks on it as hackers will be able to exploit the remaining security holes safe in the knowledge they won't get fixed.

Answer (score 5):

You seem to be using HTML5 but not using the HTML5 shiv which will allow HTML5 tags to be recognised by old browsers.

http://code.google.com/p/html5shiv/

You're also loading your stylesheet up within the HTML5 'header' tag instead of within the regular 'head' tag of the document which you don't seem to have.

Fixing those issues may help resolve your problem.

Comment: Thanks tried those but no success, the code works in IE7 and 2nd lvl menu items show in ie6 its just the 3rd level taht doers not show  /* 12 and 23*/
#nav li:hover ul, #nav li:hover li:hover ul { 
   display:block;
}

Comment: Can you post a link to your page?

Comment: page isnt live but i have created a jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/hQuYp/ unfortunately it doesnt getto the  behavior: url("csshover3.htc"); for whatever:hover

Comment: actually, the HTML5 tag he's used (`<header>`) is an error; he should be using `<head>` in this context.

Answer (score 5):

One possible solution:

`display:inline-block` has some severe bugs in IE6; I'd suggest trying `display:inline` instead.

In addition to that, you'll also need to do something to trigger IE to put the element into "hasLayout" mode. You can't do this directly as it's an internal IE flag, but setting any one of a number of CSS properties will trigger it. The most common one to use is `zoom:1` since that doesn't have much other effect, and is ignored by other browsers.

If it works, use an IE6 CSS hack to make it so that other browsers can carry on using `inline-block`. I suggest either using the underscore hack, or conditional comments.

Here's the code, using the underscore hack:

```
display:inline-block;
_display:inline;
zoom:1;
```

Hope that helps.

[Note: answer edited to include hasLayout, expand on the IE6 css hack options, and give a chunk of code]

Comment: I changed all my inline-blocks to inline and still nothing! ie6 is the devil!

Comment: Proper inline-block in older IE which do not support inline natively is `display: inline-block /* not supported in older IE*/; *zoom: 1 /* trigger hasLayout */; *display: inline /* inline + hasLayout = inline-block (!), the * before zoom an inline is a older IE hack; it works for me all the time */`

Answer (score 0):

At this point Internet Explorer 6 is dead, in fact it's beyond dead. 99.9% of IE6 user agents are bots and I've had *three* visitors who weren't show up. My browser market share is based on DOM object detection so it's actually reliable unlike statistics based on user agents. Even if you can be tricked in to thinking IE6 actually has 10% market share you still have to deal with the fact that it's been and will continue to shrink. I don't even bother to really test IE7 out as I've had only a single digit number of visitors using it. The amount of time and thus money invested in to IE6/7 at this point is beyond any justification unless a client is dead set and is so out of their mind that they would pay you $50 an hour to fix IE6/7 specific bugs.

Comment: That's fair on the wider internet, but still not true inside some corporates. There are sites out there which have legacy intranet apps which don't work with >IE6, so they have to keep using it. I know once large organisation which spent over half a million dollars trying to find a way to use IE6 on Win7.

Comment: I have seen this all to often, legacy apps only working in IE6